# Hive for bag of words (word count for each word in the dictionary)

Tags: sql, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, udf

I have a table with this structure:

```
user_id | message_id | content
   1    |      1     | "I like cats"
   1    |      1     | "I like dogs"
```

And a list of valid words in `dictionary.txt` (or an external hive table), for example:

```
I,like,dogs,cats,lemurs
```

And my goal is to generate an word-count table for each user

```
user_id  |  "I"  |  "like"  |  "dogs"  |  "cats"  |  "lemurs"
   1     |   2   |     2    |     1    |     1    |     0
```

### This is what I tried so far:

```
SELECT user_id, word, COUNT(*) 
FROM messages LATERAL VIEW explode(split(content, ' ')) lTable as word 
GROUP BY user_id,word;
```

Comment: Why the vote downs ? an explanation would be far more helpful

Comment: What is the issue with your query?

Comment: How do incorporate the predefined dictionary file and generate a row that has a constant length (not depending on the number of unique words)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this :

```
select ename, 
length(ename)-length(replace(ename,'A', '')) A,
length(ename)-length(replace(ename,'W', '')) W 
FROM EMP;
```

Else you can define a variable(your search string) and place it in the place of 'A', 'W' etc

Comment: This trick counts the amount of characters that were replaced, not the amount of replacements

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with doing Pivot on Hive, but in pig it can be possible to do.

```
DEFINE GET_WORDCOUNTS com.stackoverflow.pig.GetWordCounts('$dictionary_path');

A = LOAD .... AS user_id, message_id, content; 

C = GROUP B BY (user_id);

D = FOREACH C GENERATE group, FLATTEN(GET_WORDCOUNTS(B.content));
```

You will have to write a simple UDF `GetWordCounts` which tokenizes your input content for each grouped record, and checks with input dictionary.